# GraphQL field of type graphql object within an array

Tags: node.js, graphql, graphql-js

I have a graphQL object defined here:

```
const graphql = require('graphql');
const { GraphQLObjectType } = require('graphql');

const ProductType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Product',
    description: 'Product GraphQL Object Schemal Model',
    fields: {
        productId: { type: graphql.GraphQLString },
        SKU: { type: graphql.GraphQLString },
        quantity: { type: graphql.GraphQLFloat },
        unitaryPrice:  { type: graphql.GraphQLFloat },
        subTotal: { type: graphql.GraphQLFloat },
        discount: { type: graphql.GraphQLFloat },
        totalBeforeTax: { type: graphql.GraphQLFloat },
        isTaxAplicable: { type: graphql.GraphQLBoolean },
        unitaryTax: { type: graphql.GraphQLFloat },
        totalTax: { type: graphql.GraphQLFloat }
    }
});

module.exports.ProductType = { ProductType };
```

And then, I want to use this ProductType inside another GraphQL object, but I need that object to be an array structure, something like this:

```
const graphql = require('graphql');
const { GraphQLObjectType } = require('graphql');

const { ProductType } = require('./product');

const ShoppingCartType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'ShoppingCart',
    description: 'Shopping Cart GraphQL Object Schema Model',
    fields: {
        cartId: { type: graphql.GraphQLString },
        userId: { type: graphql.GraphQLString },
        products: [{ type: ProductType }]
    }
});

module.exports.ShoppingCartType = { ShoppingCartType };
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to wrap your existing type using the [GraphQLList](http://graphql.org/graphql-js/type/#graphqllist) wrapper, like so:

```
products: { type: new GraphQLList(ProductType) }
```