# How to define an Array datatype for GraphQL field in Type definition

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

I'm working on a Nodejs application and I'm trying to define the type below for graphQL but I cannot figure out how to define a field with a Javascript array type.

```
const graphql = require('graphql');
const {
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLID
 } = graphql;
 const { Question } = require('../../../../models');

const QuestionChoiceType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'QuestionChoiceType',
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    correctChoice: { type: GraphQLString },
    choices: [{ type: GraphQLString }]
  })
});

module.exports = QuestionChoiceType;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GraphQL field of type graphql object within an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49143973/graphql-field-of-type-graphql-object-within-an-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GraphQLList` to define a list / array :

```
const QuestionChoiceType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'QuestionChoiceType',
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    correctChoice: { type: GraphQLString },
    choices: { type: new GraphQLList(GraphQLString)}
  })
});
```